# Getting error messages during double summation

Tags: summation, index

I have two lists `xi` and `ai` of equal length, `n`. I would like to perform a sum over the elements of both lists.

This is the line that is giving me an error message:

```
Sum[
  Indexed[xi, i]*Indexed[xi, j]*(1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j])*
    (Indexed[ai, i]*Indexed[ai ,j])^0.5, 
  {{i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}}]
```

This is the error I receive:

> Sum::write: Tag List in {i, 1, n} is Protected.
>
> Sum::vloc: The variable {i, 1, n} cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.
>
> Sum::write: Tag List in {i, 1, n} is Protected.
>
> Sum::vloc: The variable {i, 1, n} cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.
>
> D::iti: Invalid index {i, 1, 4} in iterator {{i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}}.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: `Sum[Indexed[xi, i] Indexed[xi, 
   j] (1 - KroneckerDelta[i, j])*(Indexed[ai, i]*
     Indexed[ai, j])^0.5, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange and please continue to ask questions.  There is a chance that this question might be closed because it appears to be a error that could be corrected by a more detailed look at the documentation.  But don't be dismayed.  (It happens to all of us - and continues for me.)  The closing would be because the answer likely  wouldn't help a large number of folks and not because you shouldn't ask such questions when you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the syntax of the double `Sum`.

For single `Sum`,

```
Sum[i^2+j, {i, 1, n}]
```

For double do one of the following

```
Sum[Sum[i^2+j, {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, n}]
```

or

```
Sum[i^2 + j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

For more details, please visit [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html).